# A manipulation of derivative and partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n) :\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$. Let $(e_i)$ and $(e'_j)$ be the standard bases of $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$ respectively. Let $\partial f (x)$ be the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $x$, and $\partial f (x)[e_i]$ its value at $e_i$. Let $\partial_i f (x)$ be the partial derivative of $f$ at $x$ w.r.t. $e_i$.

Could you verify if my understanding is fine?

---

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\partial f (x)[e_i] &=\partial_i f (x) \\
&= \partial_i \bigg (\sum_j f_je'_j \bigg) (x) \\
&= \sum_j  \partial_i  (f_je'_j ) (x)\\
&= \sum_j  \partial_i  (e'_j f_j) (x).
\end{align}
$$

We consider $e_j'$ as a function, i.e., $e_j':\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n, t \mapsto t e_j'$. Then $e_j'$ is linear continuous and thus $\partial_i e_j' (r)[h]= e_j' (h) = h e'_j$ for all $r,h \in \mathbb R$. By chain rule, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_j  \partial_i  (e'_j f_j) (x) &= \sum_j  \partial_i  e'_j (f_j (x)) \circ \partial_i f_j (x) \\
&= \sum_j  \partial_i  e'_j (f_j (x))[ \partial_i f_j (x) ]\\
&= \sum_j \partial_i f_j (x) e'_j.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It is unclear what you want to prove. Is it $\partial f (x)[e_i] = \partial_i f_j (x) e_j$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yess, I would like to ask if my reasoning is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. It seems that you want to prove
$$\partial f (x)[e_i]  = \partial_i f_j (x) e_j . \tag{1}$$

This cannot be correct. Without going into the details of your calculations it is obvious that the LHS of $(1)$ depends on $f$ (i.e. on *all component functions $f_j$*) and the RHS depends only on a *single component function $f_j$*. In fact, if $(1)$ were correct, all $d_j =\partial_i f_j (x) e_j \in \mathbb R^m$ would agree. But all coordinates of $d_j$ except possibly the $j$-th coordinate are $0$ and this would imply that all $d_j = 0$.

Let us have a closer look at your arguments.

To avoid confusion at which place $e'_j$ has which interpretation, I would not identify $e'_j$ with a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$, but write e.g. $\bar e'_j : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$. This gives

$$\sum_j  \partial_i  (f_je'_j ) (x) = \sum_j  \partial_i  (\bar e'_j f_j) (x) . \tag{2}$$
On the LHS we have the product $f_j \cdot e'_j$, on the RHS the composition $\bar e_j \circ f_j$.  So, by the way, it would be easier to use *from the beginning* that $f = \sum_j  \bar e'_j \circ f_j$ (which is obvious).

We have $\partial \bar e'_j(r) = \bar e'_j$ for all $r$ since $\bar e'_j$ is linear. But the expression $\partial_i e_j' (r)$ does not make sense because there are no partial derivatives for a function of a single variable. Thus the equations in the last line of your question do not make sense. You can of course apply the chain rule to calculate $\partial_i  (\bar e'_j \circ f_j) (x)$, but this gives nothing else than
$$\partial_i  (\bar e'_j \circ f_j) (x) = \bar e'_j(\partial_i f_j (x)) = \partial_i f_j (x) \cdot e_j.$$
This produces
$$\sum_j  \partial_i  (\bar e'_j f_j) (x) = \sum_j \partial_i f_j (x) \cdot e_j= \partial_i f(x)$$
which is the equation you started.

**Update:**

The above calculations rely on the following facts:

Let $\phi : U\to V$ be a function between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^m, V \subset \mathbb R^n$.

1. If $m = 1$ and $\phi$ is differentiable at $x \in U$, then $\phi'(x) = d\phi(x)(1)$.
2. If $\phi$ is differentiable at $x \in U$, then all partial derivatives $\partial_v \phi (x)$ with $v \in \mathbb R^m$ exist and we have $\partial_v \phi (x) = df(x)(v)$.

The proof of 2. consists in applying the chain rule to $\phi \circ l_{x,v} : (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to V$, where $l_{x,v}(t) = x + tv$ and $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small so that $l_{x,v}((-\epsilon,\epsilon)) \subset U$ and then using 1.

We can now prove the **chain rule for partial derivatives**:

- Let $\phi : U\to V ,\psi : V \to W$ be functions between open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R^m, V \subset \mathbb R^n, W \subset \mathbb R^p$. If $\phi$ is differentiable at $x \in U$ and $\psi$ is differentiable at $\phi(x) \in V$, then
  $$\partial_i(\psi \circ\phi)(x) = d\psi(\phi(x))(\partial_i \phi(x)) .$$
  Proof. $$\partial_i(\psi \circ\phi)(x) = d(\psi \circ\phi)(x)(e_i) = (d\psi(\phi(x) \circ d\phi(x)(e_i) = d\psi(\phi(x))(d\phi(x)(e_i)) \\= d\psi(\phi(x))(\partial_i \phi(x)) . $$

Comment: Ah it's a typo, I meant $\sum_j \partial_i f_j (x) e_j$ rather than $\partial_i f_j (x) e_j$ at the end of my question...

Comment: @Akira So you get again with what you started ... and $\partial_i \bar e'_j$ has to be replaced by  $\partial \bar e'_j$ .

Comment: My bad again, I meant $\sum_j \partial_i f_j (x) e'_j$ (replacing $e_j$ with $e_j'$). Could you explain what your meant by "$\partial_i e_j^{\prime} \text { has to be replaced by } \partial e_j^{-\prime}$"?

Comment: @Akira There is no $\partial_i \bar e'_j$. The chain rule gives $\partial  (\bar e'_j \circ f_j) (x) = \partial  \bar e'_j(f_j(x)) \circ \partial f_j (x) = \bar e'_j \circ \partial f_j (x)$. Thus $\partial_i (\bar e'_j \circ f_j) (x) = \partial (\bar e'_j \circ f_j) (x) [e_i]  = (\bar e'_j \circ \partial f_j (x))[e_i] = \bar e'_j(\partial f_j (x)[e_i]) = \bar e'_j(\partial_i f_j (x)) = \partial_i f_j (x) \cdot e_j$.

Comment: It seems we get the same result, i.e., $\partial f (x)[e_i] = \sum_j \partial_i f_j (x) e'_j$. You meant I could not apply the chain rule for partial derivative on $\partial_i  (e'_j f_j) (x)$?

Comment: @Akira See my update.

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting my critical misunderstanding!